# How to handle purchase order in every sales order in Odoo?

Tags: odoo-13

Can Odoo handle purchase orders in every sales order that the items are not yet received by the warehouse?

I have this situation where customer 1 and customer 2 order the same products which are not yet in stocks (on-hand-qty = 0). So Odoo will automatically generate a purchase order to buy the items to the vendor and the company will also purchase enough stocks to compensate for the two customers? Now with 45 days lead time until the products will be receiving in the warehouse.

Example:

Item in warehouse = 0
Customer 1 buy 50 units of an item on the same day but different store.
Customer 2 buy 50 units of the same item on the same day but different store.
The company buys 200 units of the same item Since the lead time for the vendor to deliver the product is 45 days now there is Customer 3 which buys the same product on the same day but different stores but only buys 50.

Now in Odoo, it will generate 4 PO ( 3 for the Customer 1,2,3 and 1 for the company) How to make it 2 3 PO instead of 4? since it will compensate the number of items from the company's order but it will wait for 45 days? then another Customer 4 will buy the same items...etc. It will be a series of RFQ that are not necessary to do automatically.